# Connecting to AWS EC2 Windows Nano Server from OS X

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, powershell, mac-osx

I'm trying to connect to a newly spun up AWS EC2 Windows Nano Server from my OS X machine.

I'm running powershell from OSX and am [following these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html#connecting-nano)

`PS /Users/alex/Projects> $ip = "ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"`

```
PS /Users/alex/Projects> Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts $ip  

Set-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'WSMan' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts $ip
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WSMan:String) [Set-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

I tried to ignore this and move onto the remaining 2 steps:

```
PS /Users/alex/Projects> $user = "$ip\Administrator"                                                                                        
PS /Users/alex/Projects> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential $user     

Windows PowerShell credential request
Enter your credentials.
Password for user ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com\Administrator: ********************************

Enter-PSSession : MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential $user
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (ec2-x-x-x-x...e.amazonaws.com:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Answer (score 1):

See powershell for macOS known issue list:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/KNOWNISSUES.md#remoting-support

> Client-side remoting from Linux/macOS is not supported with the initial package. The work is being done in the psl-omi-provider repo.

Answer (score -1):

You are wanting an interactive shell login?  If so, why not ssh from a Mac OS X terminal?  The command would be something like:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/filename.pem ec2-user@eyourmachine.amazonaws.com

where the pem file can get created following these instructions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: Does the EC2 Windows Nano Server AMI run sshd by default?

Comment: There's no ec2-user on Windows instances and there's no default SSH process running so this "solution" is just noise.  Is there a way you can delete it?